# Shell Pipelines

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to understand this Shell line:

```bsh
grep ^x06 ssh_known_hosts |
ssh-keygen -l -f -| 
\sed -e 's/^.*\(SHA256:\S\+\).*(\([^)]\+\))/\2: \1/' >fp
```

- So with `grep` we are basically searching for the data `ssh_unknown_hosts`. What is `^x06` used for?
- With the `ssh-keygen` command we are generating a SSH key with `-l`. What's the `-f` used for?
- The last line I didn't get.

Answer (score 5):

`grep` is searching the file `ssh_known_hosts` for the line (or lines) starting with `x06` (`^` indicates a beginning of line in a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)) and outputs it.

From `man ssh-keygen`:

```
 ssh-keygen -l [-f input_keyfile]

[...]

 -l      Show fingerprint of specified public key file.  Private RSA1 keys
         are also supported.  For RSA and DSA keys ssh-keygen tries to
         find the matching public key file and prints its fingerprint.  If
         combined with -v, an ASCII art representation of the key is sup‐
         plied with the fingerprint.
```

So `ssh-keygen -l -f -` reads key from standard input (that is, from the line that has been output by `grep`) and outputs its fingerprint (`-` used as a filename indicates standard input).

The `sed` part is the most difficult. One needs to understand well regular expressions to understand what it does.

`sed` runs the command `s/pattern/replacement/` on each line of input, that is, replaces `pattern` with `replacement` and copies the line to standard output. If the `pattern` is not found in the line, the line is copied unchanged.

The `pattern` `sed` is looking for is: `^.*\(SHA256:\S\+\).*(\([^)]\+\))`. It is a regular expression of course.

It can be broken down as follows:

- beginning of line (`^`), followed by zero or more of any characters (`.*`), followed by first **group** (the part between `\( ... \)`; we get to the details later), followed by zero or more of any characters (`.*`), followed by second **group**, which is enclosed in literal parentheses `(\( ... \))`.
- The first group is `SHA256:\S\+`. This means a literal string `SHA256:`, followed by one or more non-space characters (`\S\+`) - however, it should be noted that not all `sed` implementations will support `\S` as an indication of non-space character. So first group matches `SHA256:` followed by any characters, up to the first space.
- The second group is `[^)]\+`, that is, one or more characters that are not equal to the closing parenthesis. Taking into account that the entire group is placed in parentheses, the second group matches any string placed in parentheses, up to the closing parenthesis.

Summing up, `sed` searches in line for a pattern consisting of `SHA256:` plus any non-space characters, and then any string placed in parentheses, with anything between them.

The matched pattern is replaced with `\2: \1` which is the text matching the second group (`\2`), colon, space and the text matching the first group (`\1`).

For example, if `ssh-keygen` output contains a line like

```
begin something SHA256:123456 middle something (text inside parens) end something
```

`sed` will replace that line with

```
text inside parens: SHA256:123456 end something
```

Lines that don't contain the pattern won't be changed.

Comment: Hey very kind of you for helping me out I did understand most of it but im wondering 
what the Input Output redirect of the shell and the Pipes is doing

Comment: Where does the Computer save the files ?

Comment: @Sparta Which files? In this code, `ssh_known_hosts` is the input file and `fp` is the output file where final output from `sed` is written. As there is no path specified, both files are in current directory.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help guys i really Appreciate it